# ggplot2 multiplot using changing variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create multiple plots using ggplot2 that is then gathered in using multiplot. However, when I try to create X graphs I end up with X of the same graph.

My problem code pretty much boils down to this, asuming `df` is the dataframe

```
library(ggplot2)

i = 1
j = 2
xVar = df[[i]]
yVar = df[[j]]
plot1 = ggplot(data = df, aes(xVar, yVar)) + geom_point(shape=1)

i = 1
j = 3
xVar = df[[i]]
yVar = df[[j]]
plot2 = ggplot(data = df, aes(xVar, yVar)) + geom_point(shape=1)

multiplot(plot1,plot2, cols=2)
```

At this point plot1 is equal to plot2 and I dont understand why.

My full code if interested:

```
n = 1
columns = colnames(df)
plots = list()

for(i in 3:7)
{
    for(j in (i+1):7)
    {
        if(j < 8 & i < 7) {
        xVar = df[[i]]
        yVar = df[[j]]

        plots[[n]] = ggplot(data = df, aes(x=xVar, y=yVar)) +
                geom_point(shape=1) +
                labs(x=columns[[i]], y=columns[[j]]) +
                theme(axis.title=element_text(size=8))
        n = n + 1
        }
    }
}

multiplot(plotlist = plots, cols=3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of things going on here.

First, it is a really, *really*, ***really*** bad idea to use external variables in calls to `aes(...)`. The arguments to `aes(...)` are evaluated in the context of the `data=...` argument, so in the context of `df` in your case. If that fails they are evaluated in the global environment. So it is highly preferable to do something like this:

```
gg <- data.frame(x=df[[i]],y=df[[j]])
plots[[n]] = ggplot(data = gg, aes(x,y)) +...
```

Second, `ggplot` stores the *expressions* from `aes(...)` and evaluates them when the plot is rendered (so, during the call to `multiplot(...)`). All of your plots use variables named `xVar` and `yVar` in `aes(...)`. So when these plots are rendered, `ggplot` uses whatever is stored in those variables at the time - presumably from the last plot definition. That's why all your plots look like the last one. This is the reference to "lazy evaluation" in the other answer.

On the other hand, `ggplot` evaluates the `data=...` argument immediately, and stores the dataset as part of the plot definition (in the `gtable`). So creating different data frames (called `gg` above), for each plot will work.

Finally, it looks like you are trying to create a pairs plot (every column vs. every other column, more or less). Unless this is a homework assignment, there are much easier ways to do this. You could use `ggpairs(...)` in the `GGally` package (which uses grid graphics), or you could do it this way using basic ggplot with facets:

```
# make up some data
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(700),nc=7))
df[4] <- 1+2*df[3] + rnorm(100)
df[5] <- 3*df[3] - 2*df[4] + rnorm(100)
df[6] <- -10*df[5] + rnorm(100)

# you start here...
gg.pairs <- function(data) { # scatterplot matrix using ggplot facets
  require(ggplot2)
  require(data.table)
  require(reshape2)    # for melt(...)

  DT <- data.table(melt(cbind(id=1:nrow(data),data),id="id"),key="id")
  gg <- DT[DT,allow.cartesian=T]
  setnames(gg,c("id","H","x","V","y"))
  ggplot(gg[as.integer(gg$H)<as.integer(gg$V),], aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_point(shape=1) + 
    facet_grid(V~H, scales="free")
}
gg.pairs(df[3:7])
```

[image]

Comment: It was indeed a pairs plot I was trying to make and creating a new dataframe as you suggested did work. However, it left me wondering if there is an equivalent of the `new` keyword as found in other languages that will instantiate an object?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is in R lazy evaluation. Indeed what happens is that `plot1` and `plot2` are not created when you assign it but when you call it, and at this moment there is only one copy (the last one) of `xVar`and `yVar` and plots are the same

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't explain what is happening, but a workaround is to use column names instead of columns with`aes_string`.  The following makes two unique plots in `multiplot` for me, and this change could easily be incorporated into your plot loop.

```
dat = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y1 = rnorm(10), y2 = rpois(10, 5))

xVar = names(dat)[1]
yVar = names(dat)[2]
plot1 = ggplot(data = dat, aes_string(xVar, yVar)) + geom_point(shape=1)

yVar = names(dat)[3]
plot2 = ggplot(data = dat, aes_string(xVar, yVar)) + geom_point(shape=1)

multiplot(plot1, plot2, cols=2)
```